# React router dom on page refresh error - cannot read property of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, undefined, page-refresh, react-router-dom

I am working on react redux firebase app. Inm App.js i get all the posts with title and body. I made the title a clickable link and passed the key as paraeter (see the code below).

When i click it takes me to PostDetails page. Everything is working fine. The post is in the state (i can see in redux devtools, console log etc).

> But as soon as I refresh the page, i get error that says: TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Any help would be highly appriciated. I am using react-router-dom for routing. Thanks!

index.js - routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/:id" component={PostDetail} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

App.js - component that has post title as a clickable link:

```
renderPosts() {
    return _.map(this.props.posts, (post, key) => {
      return (
        <div key={key}>
          <Link to={`/${key}`}>
            <h3 className="card-title">{post.title}</h3>
          </Link>
          <p>{post.body}</p>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.deletePost(key)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
        {this.renderPosts()}
    )
  }
  export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts, savePost, deletePost })(App));
```

PostDetail - component that displays full post:

```
class PostDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        const { post } = this.props;
        console.log(post);
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to={'/'}>Go Home</Link>
                <div>
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                    <p>{post.body}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return { post: state.posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(PostDetail));
```

Comment: can you verify that you get `ownProps.match.params.id` right in the mapStateToProps function

Comment: when i console log this.props.post in PostDetail component. I get only title and body, no params. {body: "by mozilla", title: "JavaScript"}

Comment: I reach post detail page fine. Once i refresh the page, i get error..

Comment: once you refresh the page, your Redux state is lost and hence you would get that error

Comment: yes, think about persisting the state in `localStorage` if you want that kind of functionality. How do you populate the Redux store ?

Comment: There must be a way to fix that.. If i dont render {post.title} in PostDetail component. then even when i refresh , the rest of the content is there, no errors..

Comment: So when you refresh, you might be calling an API to repopulate your redux state `post` that takes awhile and before it is available, in the render you use `post.title` which throws an error, so if you are getting the post details after refresh then you might need to add a conditional check before using `post.title` and similarly other keys

Comment: Your component that you render should be running actions to fetch that data. `mapDispatchToProps` the relevant actions in this component. Any 'root' page should have the ability to grab its own items from the store.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I have a LoadingComponent that is wrapping the Routes that renders children component depending on loading state true or false like so:render() {
    const { postsLoading, children, posts } = this.props;
    return postsLoading === false && posts ? <div>{children}</div> : <Loading />;
} .  Thanks to withRouter!

Comment: @RyanDhungel, then please post your answer as the correct one so others may benefit from the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

this will be solved by this `post?.title` it will first wait for the data in post. Its alternative to conditional rendering

Comment: Please explain what effect this has

Comment: Well, it will first wait for the data in post. Its alternative to conditional rendering